# Portfolio Page --- How to move down to the next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class= "pageThree container-fluid">
  <div class= "row">
    <div class= "col-md-12" id= "protxt">   
      <h1>Projects</h1>
      <h3>Work in progress</h3>
    </div>
    <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
    <a href= "http://www.freecodecamp.com/map#">
    <img src= "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/wide-social-banner.png"     class= "img-responsive">
    </a>  
    </div>
    <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
    <a href= "http://i.imgur.com/dLx8nrg.jpg">
    <img src= "http://i.imgur.com/dLx8nrg.jpg" class= "img-responsive">
    </a>   
    </div> 
    <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
    <a href= "http://www.epicodus.com/">
    <img src= "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5524448ee4b0d6f6b83ab9e2/t/55244514e4b08a    d5c0f51a01/1450291270689/?format=1500w" class= "img-responsive">
    </a>   
    </div> 

  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to finish up this part of my portfolio by making a second row with three elements in it like the first row so I will have a total of six "projects" , three on each row. This is probably very simple but I have been trying all sorts of things and can't seem to figure it out.

My other question which is kinda optional at the moment is how do I make all the image links the same size? I was messing around with this earlier and had a little bit of success but I ended up not being able to get the images centered again after re-sizing which caused everything to move left.

My CSS:

```
#projects {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

This is the complete CodePen so far: 
http://codepen.io/mikerand/pen/QjRVYP

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of cols in a row should add up to 12. Here you have two sets of cols like that. A full width `col-md-12` and three `col-md-4`. To begin with, put these two in separate rows. Then add another row with three `col-md-4`.

```
<div class= "pageThree container-fluid">
    <div class= "row">
        <div class= "col-md-12" id= "protxt">   
            <h1>Projects</h1>
            <h3>Work in progress</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "row">
        <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
            <a href= "http://www.freecodecamp.com/map#">
                <img src= "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/wide-social-banner.png"     class= "img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
            <a href= "http://i.imgur.com/dLx8nrg.jpg">
                <img src= "http://i.imgur.com/dLx8nrg.jpg" class= "img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
            <a href= "http://www.epicodus.com/">
                <img src= "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5524448ee4b0d6f6b83ab9e2/t/55244514e4b08a    d5c0f51a01/1450291270689/?format=1500w" class= "img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "row">
        <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
            <a href= "http://www.freecodecamp.com/map#">
                <img src= "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/wide-social-banner.png"     class= "img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
            <a href= "http://i.imgur.com/dLx8nrg.jpg">
                <img src= "http://i.imgur.com/dLx8nrg.jpg" class= "img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class= "col-md-4 container-fluid" id= "projects">
            <a href= "http://www.epicodus.com/">
                <img src= "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5524448ee4b0d6f6b83ab9e2/t/55244514e4b08a    d5c0f51a01/1450291270689/?format=1500w" class= "img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. I figured it out in a bit more complicated way as soon as I submitted the question but yes, this is much more simple. Thank you man

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.